# How to use Windows Firewall to block?

Tags: firewall, blocking, windows-firewall

Can someone help me figure out how to use Windows 10 Firewall to block internet access of some programs? I have some portable apps and would like to understand how to block them from the internet.

Here's what I tried but did not work:

1. Went to "Outbound Rules" in Windows Firewall.
2. Created new rule and selected "Program". Gave the path for the .exe in the portable application's folder.
3. Tested by running the program and selecting "Check for new version" under the About section.
4. I expect the program to be unable to check for new version. But it successfully reports back that a newer version is available.
5. I tried the same method with a few other programs, but wasn't able to block any.

What am I missing?